# How can I get choice function to return a different result under the while loop

Tags: python, random, while-loop

I have this code that works fine, but there's a minor issue. The first choice function works well and returns a random state in the question. And if the answer is yes, it works fine and prints what I want. But when the answer is no, I'd like the question to come with a different state name. But the second choice function, under the while loop, returns the same state as the first question. I thought another usage of choice would return another random state name but apparently, it's not so.

Here's the code:

```
from random import choice

states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California',
        'CO': 'Colorado',
        'CT': 'Connecticut',
        'DC': 'District of Columbia',
        'DE': 'Delaware',
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'GA': 'Georgia',
        'GU': 'Guam',
        'HI': 'Hawaii',
        'IA': 'Iowa',
        'ID': 'Idaho',
        'IL': 'Illinois',
        'IN': 'Indiana',
        'KS': 'Kansas',
        'KY': 'Kentucky',
        'LA': 'Louisiana',
        'MD': 'Maryland',
        'MA': 'Massachusetts',
        'ME': 'Maine',
        'MI': 'Michigan',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
        'MT': 'Montana',
        'NA': 'National',
        'NC': 'North Carolina',
        'ND': 'North Dakota',
        'NE': 'Nebraska',
        'NH': 'New Hampshire',
        'NJ': 'New Jersey',
        'NM': 'New Mexico',
        'NV': 'Nevada',
        'NY': 'New York',
        'OH': 'Ohio',
        'OK': 'Oklahoma',
        'OR': 'Oregon',
        'PA': 'Pennsylvania',
        'PR': 'Puerto Rico',
        'RI': 'Rhode Island',
        'SC': 'South Carolina',
        'SD': 'South Dakota',
        'TN': 'Tennessee',
        'TX': 'Texas',
        'UT': 'Utah',
        'VA': 'Virginia',
        'VI': 'Virgin Islands',
        'VT': 'Vermont',
        'WA': 'Washington',
        'WI': 'Wisconsin',
        'WV': 'West Virginia',
        'WY': 'Wyoming'
}

state_list = list(states.values())

choice = choice(state_list)

question = "Would you like to move to {}?: ".format(choice)

answer = input(question).strip().lower()

while answer!= "yes":

    question = "Okay. How about {}?: ".format(choice)
    answer = input(question).strip().lower()

print("Sounds good! Let's go there!")
```

Comment: The choice function isn't *inside* the `while` loop, maybe try changing that? You're not calling anything, just referring to the same value again. Also you've shadowed the function with the value it returned, which isn't helping.

Comment: `choice` is never getting updated inside loop. There's no wonder that you get same state name every time. `choice = choice(state_list)` later throws *"'str' object not callable"* error.

Comment: Remove the line `choice = choice(state_list)` and use `format(choice(state_list))` instead.

Comment: With 'choice = choice(...)' you're overriding _choice_ function!!! Use a different name, like "chosen_state = choice(...)" (and put it inside the loop)

Comment: @ekhumoro - thank you so much!! that did the trick. so i guess the way i originally had it, it wasn't getting updated, it was just repeating the choice variable as i'd defined it before the while loop. repeating it was just repeating the same variable. lesson learned! thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

Your problem is that you find random from state_list

```
choice = choice(state_list)
```

and you treat is as function -> you think whenever you use it, it will generate random choice. No. Choice is a variable in which you saved random from state_list. In your loop, you are basicly calling choice which is nothing more than saved variable.

You can however create function generate_choice() that will do what you want

```
import random
def generate_choice():
    return random.choice(state_list)
```

so now you can always call

```
new_choice = generate_choice()
```

to get new random element from state_list

**Also you did great mistake by doing**

```
choice = choice(state_list)
```

**because you destroyed your imported function choice and you put instead of this function a result of this function, so now you cant call it again.**

**Solution**

```
...
#
#choice = choice(state_list) <-- here you destroyed your function
# instead import module like this:
import random

choice = random.choice(state_list) <--- now you are save
question = "Would you like to move to {}?: ".format(choice) 

answer = input(question).strip().lower()

while answer!= "yes":

    question = "Okay. How about {}?: ".format(random.choice(state_list)) # generate choice everytime new
    answer = input(question).strip().lower()

print("Sounds good! Let's go there!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I just tried it and it works perfectly! Makes perfect sense too. I appreciate the detailed answer! Thanks for taking the time to give me such detail!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change the choice variable in every iteration, otehrwise it will chose the same state each loop. Try this:

```
while answer!= "yes":
    choice = choice(state_list)
    question = "Okay. How about {}?: ".format(choice)
    answer = input(question).strip().lower()
```

You should rename your choice variable with something that is not a function name and it should be working

Comment: In the next iteration of `while` you're gonna see some `TypeError` saying `choice` is not callable.  Test your code first, and don't shadow the objects.

Comment: That does not answer question completely, still throws error.

Comment: Use a different name for assigned "choice": chosen_state = choice(...)

Comment: Remove the line `choice = choice(state_list)` and use `format(choice(state_list))` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Sz. Zsolt! I tried doing that, but I get the "object not callable" error when the answer is no. I've been able to avoid that only with @ekhumoro's suggestion.

Comment: I unfortunately upvoted this as I didnt noticed great mistake in the code. Check my explanation -> Mainly the bottom

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, thanks for the correction, @Martin

Comment: looks like 3 of us and you got caught on such a tricky thing :D

Comment: I didnt want to steal your answer, but when I noticed your mistake, I grabbed the chance :)